# Add a popup to each marker in the Folium map instantly when the marker appears in the map

Tags: python, folium

I have a Folium map, where the markers (coordinates) appear based on the time. what I want is that when a marker appears on the map, its popup would be seen instantly, independently of the click. I have read the following code:

```
def create_geojson_features(df):
 features = []

 for index, row in df.iterrows():
    feature = {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type':'Point', 
            'coordinates':[row['longitude'],row['latitude']]
        },
        'properties': {
            'time': row['timestamp'],
            'icon': 'Marker',
            'popup': folium.Popup(show=True, html=row['ip']),

            }
    }    
    features.append(feature)
return features
```

and then I make a GeoJSON by the following code:

```
    start_geojson= create_geojson_features(new_df)
    geojson = {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'features': start_geojson}
```

then:

```
       from folium.plugins import TimestampedGeoJson
       import folium 

     nyc_map = folium.Map(location=[new_df.latitude.mean(),new_df.longitude.mean()],       tiles='OpenStreetMap', zoom_start=2)

     TimestampedGeoJson(
     geojson,
     period='PT1M',
     add_last_point=True,
     auto_play=True,
     loop=True,
     max_speed=1,
     loop_button=True,
     date_options='YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
     ).add_to(nyc_map)
```

But I have received the following error:

> Object of type Popup is not JSON serializable

How to solve this problem?